# Convert unix_timestamp to utc_timestamp using pyspark, unix_timestamp not working

Tags: pyspark, unix-timestamp, date-conversion

I have a string column that has unix_tstamp in a pyspark dataframe.

```
unix_tstamp       utc_stamp

1547741586462     2019-01-17 16:13:06:462
1547741586562     2019-01-17 16:13:06:562
1547741586662     2019-01-17 16:13:06:662
1547741586762     2019-01-17 16:13:06:762
1547741586862     2019-01-17 16:13:06:862
```

I exactly want to perform conversion in the above format but I'm getting null when I tried the below method,

data.withColumn("utc_stamp", unix_timestamp('unix_tstamp',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))

Am I missing something or is there any other way?

Comment: Your pattern doesn't match. There's no `'T'` in your strings and there shouldn't be a `Z` at the end. Try `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"`

Comment: It is still showing null in the new column even after trying your format.

Comment: That last period should be a colon. You have to make your your strings match the pattern. `null` means the pattern is wrong. Do a search for Java simple date format

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the format like this:

```
df = df.withColumn('utc_stamp', F.from_unixtime('Timestamp', format="YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))

df.show(truncate=False)

+----------+-----------------------+
|Timestamp |utc_stamp              |
+----------+-----------------------+
|1579887004|2020-01-24 18:30:04.000|
|1579887004|2020-01-24 18:30:04.000|
+----------+-----------------------+
```

> **Sample Data**

```
# today's datestamp
d = [[1579887004],
     [1579887004],
    ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(d, ['Timestamp'])
```